# NAudio Loopback Record Crackle Sound Error

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm recording sound via the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` and write it to an MP3-File via the `NAudio.Lame` lib:

```
LAMEPreset quality = LAMEPreset.ABR_320;

audiostream = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
audiostream.DataAvailable += stream_DataAvailable;
audiostream.RecordingStopped += stream_RecordingStopped;

mp3writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\Music\record_temp.mp3",
    audiostream.WaveFormat, quality);

audiostream.StartRecording();
```

When the user presses the stop-recording-button, I save the MP3 and stop the recording:

```
mp3writer.Flush();
audiostream.Dispose();
mp3writer.Dispose();
```

All works fine, **except** that **the output file has some disturbing crackle noises in it**. (See [here](https://soundcloud.com/tom-neu-8/naudio-record-crackles/s-pQ1p5) for example). I think it might be the case, that my computer is a bit to slow to do the process of compressing and writing the audio data in realtime, so some of the values get lost, but that is just my guess

**Edit**: When recording to WAVE, the errors dont appear.

What may be the problem here and how could I possibly solve it / work around it?

Answer (score 0):

start off by saving your audio to a WAV file. Does that have crackles in it? If so the crackles are coming from the soundcard. If not, they are coming from the encoding to MP3 code.

Comment: Like I meintioned in the question, the crackles don't appear when recording to wave

Comment: OK so next step is take the WAV file you converted and convert it offline to MP3 with LameMp3FileWriter. See if that's where the crackles are coming in.

Comment: I guess my machine is too slow to do the encoding in real time. I'll try that